# How to get all the cookies issued by a webpage in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get all the cookies issued by a certain page.

Using the Chrome's developer tool, I can see that a page issues adsense cookies. But when I try using HttpWebRequest I cant see these cookie using response.Cookies.

Example, visiting the page: http://smallbiztrends.com/ I can see that there is adsense cookies using the developer tool but I cant access this cookie using HttpWebRequest...

Does anyone has a solution for this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Those cookies come most probably from the several `<iframe>` on the html page served by the website.

If you want to get all those cookies you need to fetch the html and then parse it to look for all the  tags and then load their `src` attributes.

[image]

Do notice that some of these might also require the javascript to run ... You would basically need all the functionality a browser offers. A simple WebRequest is not enough.

If you're going to give it a try make sure you create a [`CookieContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) and set that instance everytime you do a request:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.CookieContainer = cookies;

// lots of handling 

// next request
req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.CookieContainer = cookies; // reuse cookies
```